# How do I change the size of the hint when it shrinks?

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin, material-design

I am trying to create a player form for my android application. The problem I am having is that when the hint shrinks, you can barely see it. I tried changing the size of the text and the TextInputLayout with no luck.

```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/first_name_text_input_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/keyline_2"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/keyline_2"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/keyline_2"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:errorTextColor="@color/color_error"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/player_initial_text"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/last_name_input_text_layout">

   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/first_name_input_text"
                    android:layout_width="400dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                    android:hint="@string/first_name_hint"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/color_hint_grey"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/alternate_got_no1d"
                    android:textSize="30sp"/>
   </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you peek at https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/ ? You'd need to update the textAppearance of the hint (https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout.html#attr_TextInputLayout_hintTextAppearance) (My guess)

Comment: Try to apply @style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox to your TextInputLayout